# What does "rx" or "bx" mean as the third argument of ax.plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This code is for KMeans Machine Learning:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
centroid_colors=['bx','rx']
x = y = [1,2,3]

for color in centroid_colors:
    ax.plot(x, y, color)
```

what is the meaning of bx, rx here, I can see mentioned as centroid colors, but I could not find these two color code from the color code of matplotlib.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third argument is not actually *color*, but *format*, including the color, marker style and line style. The syntax of the `fmt` argument of `ax.plot(x,y,fmx)` is:

```
fmt = '[marker][line][color]'
```

The [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) also gives examples:

```
'b'    # blue markers with default shape
'or'   # red circles
'-g'   # green solid line
'--'   # dashed line with default color
'^k:'  # black triangle_up markers connected by a dotted line
```

The `bx` means "blue x" (i.e. [color][marker]). It seems that the matplotlib plot function is clever enough to understand the `fmt` even if the ordering of the items in the argument are mixed. The docs say (emphasis mine)

> Other combinations such as [color][marker][line] are also supported,
> but note that their parsing **may be ambiguous**.

Hence, I would personally use `xb` over `bx`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Thank you, and welcome to SO. If this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) it states that it is the style of marker. In this case a red "x" and a blue "x".